# PHP Multiple Checkbox;

Tags: php

I have problem, I am trying to create a form with a few checkboxes, each assigned a different value, i just can update value first and last, between not working, can you help me?
Check.php

```
<div class="top-on">

    <div class="top-on1">
        <p class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['username'];?></p>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control col-sm-12" name="edit_level">
        <?php
        global $pdo;
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM level");
        while ( $row_c = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            ?>
        <option  <?php if($row_c["level"]==$row["level"])
        {
            echo "selected=\"selected\"";
        }?>
        value="<?php echo $row_c['level']?>"> <?php echo $row_c['name'];?> </opition>

        <?php } ?>

        </select>
    </div>
    <label style="float: right;"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="idlevel[]" value="<?php     echo $row['id'];?>"> </label>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

page Control.php

```
function edit_level(){
            global $pdo;
            $sql1="SELECT * From user ";
            $stmt1 = $pdo->query($sql1);
            if(isset($this->btnlevel))
            {
                for($i=0;$i<$stmt1->rowCount();$i++){

                    $elve=$this->idlevel[$i];
                    $sql ="UPDATE user SET level='$this->editlevel' WHERE id='".$elve."'";
                    $upt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $upt->execute();

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: not sure what you need in here.. just an observation, you got a typo <opition>